# Jquery function working on some browsers

Tags: jquery

I have created a validation of an input text box which only accepts numeric values, and also only 8 digits, but it doesn't work on Safari and Internet Explorer. Can anyone help me making it work please?

```js
 $("#user_phone").keydown(function (e) {
       
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||(e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
       
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                 
                 return;
        }
         
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }


        }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input maxlength="8" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile eg 99999999" name="user_phone" id="user_phone" required>
```

Note: if any syntax error just neglect it. must be caused by copy pasting.

Comment: *"if any syntax error just neglect it"* Fix it. Your snippet does not work. What's it there for then?

Comment: Sorry brother I did from mobile. Lemme fix

Comment: `let it happen, don't do anything` is not valid Javascript.

Comment: Yeah done! fixed it

Comment: I tried it in Safari, it seems to work. What do I have to do to see the problem?

Comment: It accepts alphabets too... other than that `maxlength` doesnt work too

Comment: I tried entering alphabetic characters in OS X Safari, it doesn't accept them.

Comment: Then I'm gonna throw my iphone out of the window

Comment: let is new type variabel ,You can see my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code :

```
<script>
$('#user_phone').keypress(function(e){
    var phone = $(this).val();
        if(phone.length >= 8){
            alert('Not more the 8 char');
            return false;   
        }

    var key_codes = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 0, 8];
        if (!($.inArray(e.which, key_codes) >= 0)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }       
})  
</script>
```

Comment: What's the difference would it make?

Comment: Its take only number and not allow user to enter more than 8 numbers, i have checked on my iphone

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $("#user_phone").keydown(function (e) {
       
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||(e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
       
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                 "let it happen, don 't do anything";
                 return;
        }
         
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }


        }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input maxlength="8" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile eg 99999999" name="user_phone" id="user_phone" required>
```